# Website is stalling for a few seconds on initial load

Tags: amazon-elb

I have a website that consistently has a initial delay anywhere from 2 - 10 seconds. Using chrome dev tools I can see that the delay is marked Stalled under the Connection Start. See image:

[image: Example my of stall]

Other sites for example have very little stall 1-2ms See example image:

[[image: Typical site's stall][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJGEm.png)

How can I best identify what is happening durning this stall? I am using an AWS Application Load balancer and have followed the configuration according to their Docs.

What is a good approach to identify the cause of this issue? Where can I start?